# C program to find first N palindrome numbers prints nothing

Tags: c, palindrome

I am trying to make a program to print the `N` first palindrome numbers(not until `N` but the first `N` numbers). The problem is that I run it, I give a number and it just exists without doing nothing or printing something.

Something that I tried, is to make a similar program to check only one number at a time and found that in the `if` condition where I check the number, if I write `N == reverse` I get

> 0 is a or not a pal number

but If I save the original number in a variable like the `N1` and instead write `N1 == reverse` I get the actual number

> N(whatever the number is) is or not a pal number

and not just a 0. I tried to do it in this program but still didn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N, i, j, reverse, curNum, rem, N1;

    printf("Give N numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    N1 = N;

    for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            rem = curNum % 10;
            curNum = curNumr / 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + rem;
        }

        if (N1 == reverse)
        {
            printf("%d", N1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `reverse` to `0` for each number that's entered.

Comment: And `curNum` also needs to be set somewhere

Comment: Note that `for (i = 0; i <= N; i++)` will iterate `N + 1` times.

Comment: It might be easier to construct these instead, since you can take any N digit number and then either append all of the digits reversed to make a palindrome with an even number of digits) or all the digits except the last one to make a palindrome with an odd number of digits. Work through increasing numbers of digits until you have created N.

Comment: Exactly. The first 10 palindromic numbers are `0` thru `9`. The next 9 are `11`, `22`  through `99` and so on.